# Why not getting JQuery effects on browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm a novice in JQuery, I'm trying some simple code but not getting the desired out put on browser. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<title>Product</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('p').css('color','#red');
</script>

<p> 
This is for test, supposed to show in red!!
</p>
</body>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I used firefox to observe the result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a single question where we can point all these questions to? We're getting an awful lot of questions missing DOM ready...

Comment: @JosephSilber Yeah, the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready). But some beginners don't care to read The Basics for some reason.

Comment: ok guys, I know its hard to feel like a beginner when you already went past those days, but for your kind info, I'm not the one who want to do some google work & start using JQery Magic, I'm reading a PDF named "JQuery: Novice to Ninja", I want to learn all the basics, but somehow missed the points which I shouldn't, but still I'm not the wrong guy. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to work with dom when it is not built. In jQuery there is a standard event handler for  that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('p').css('color', 'red');
});
```

**Updated:** Also as here was mentioned you should use `red` instead of `#red`, because `#` is used for hex codes of colors.

Comment: Also `#red` should be just `red`...

Comment: I updated the code but still not showing in red, is there anything else to do?

Comment: @Jobskuk do you have jQuery at `../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js`?

Comment: I got things solved, thanks all for the help.

Comment: Note that the _other_ way to solve this (without a document ready handler) is to move the script block to after the element(s) it tries to manipulate - a common practice is to put the script as the last thing before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need wrap the code in the dom ready callback.

```
$(function() {
  $('p').css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
<head>
    <title>Product</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document.ready(function(){
            $('p').css("color","red");
    })
</script>

<p> 
    This is for test, supposed to show in red!!
</p>
```

Comment: thanks..the problem is solved now. Thanks for your time.